# How to handle this scenario in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java 1.8. 
I have two data sets.

```
Dataset<Company> firstDataset = //get/read data from oracle company table.


Dataset<CompanyTransaction> secondDataset = //get/read data from oracle company_transaction table.
```

`Company` has columns like `"companyId","companyName","companyRegion","column4","column5",...etc`

`CompanyTransaction` has columns like `"companyId","transactionId","transactionType","column4","column5",...etc`

For each companyId from firstDataset , I need to fetch respective companyId data from CompanyTransaction

How can this be achieved using spark ?

Comment: Please use `Dataset.join` operator as in the answer. Anything left to answer?

Answer (score 3):

Join both datasets based on company_id and select all columns from second dataset. Code should look something as below: (Not Tested)

```
Dataset<Row> finalDf = firstDataset.join(secondDataset 
,firstDataset.col("companyId").equalTo(secondDataset.col("companyid"), 
"inner").select(secondDataset .col("*))
finalDF.show()
```

Comment: If you have a composite key, it should be included in join columns.. if you specifically want perform for each operation, please explore "Mappartition" in spark

Comment: thats true. But thats the only optimized way of performing for each that we can enforce from our side. as computation will go to each partiion